# Subtract two dataframes of different size, but maintain at least the size of the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have a DataFrame df and from there I want to subtract df2.

The caveat is that I want df to maintain the same size, and for every element in df, I want to minus df2 (if there is not such unique index/column in df2), it would just be `df(i,j) - 0` (as no such index/column found in df2).

Example:

**df:**

```
Date    Blue    Dog Apple
1/1/2016    3   4   2
1/1/2015    3   4   2
1/1/2014    3   4   2
1/1/2013    3   4   2
1/1/2013    3   4   2
1/1/2013    3   4   2
```

**df2:**

```
Date    Apple   Blue    Cat
1/1/2017    1   3   2
1/1/2016    1   3   2
1/1/2015    1   3   2
1/1/2014    1   3   2
```

I want df - df2 to look like this:

```
Date    Blue    Dog Apple
1/1/2016    0   4   1
1/1/2015    0   4   1
1/1/2014    0   4   1
1/1/2013    3   4   2
1/1/2012    3   4   2
1/1/2011    3   4   2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fill back the gaps:

```
(df-df2).combine_first(df).reindex_like(df).astype(int)
Out[45]: 
          Blue  Dog  Apple
Date                      
1/1/2016     0    4      1
1/1/2015     0    4      1
1/1/2014     0    4      1
1/1/2013     3    4      2
1/1/2012     3    4      2
1/1/2011     3    4      2
```

Answer (score 4):

Boud already has you covered with a great answer, but piggybacking off of it, you could also just provide a fill value of 0 to [`df.subtract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) and then [`reindex_like`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html).

```
>>> df.subtract(df2, fill_value=0).reindex_like(df).astype(int)
          Blue  Dog  Apple
Date                      
1/1/2016     0    4      1
1/1/2015     0    4      1
1/1/2014     0    4      1
1/1/2013     3    4      2
1/1/2012     3    4      2
1/1/2011     3    4      2
```

This looks like it is faster from a (*rough*) benchmark, as we can avoid the `combine_first` combination.

```
%timeit df.subtract(df2, fill_value=0).reindex_like(df).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.63 ms per loop

%timeit (df-df2).combine_first(df).reindex_like(df).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.69 ms per loop
```